# How to use correctly group by in CakePHP3

Tags: cakephp, group-by, cakephp-3.0, query-builder

I want to calculate the number of people in a room based on the model Reservation field `Reservation.people` (int).

Error:

> Reservation not Associated in group

What am I doing wrong?

```
$hostel = $this->Hostel->get($id, [
    'contain' => [
        'Room' => [
            'conditions' => [
                'Room.status' => '0'
            ],
            'sort' => [
                'Room.number'
            ],
            'Reservation' => [
                'fields' => [
                    'reservation_room_id' => 'Reservation.room_id',
                    'sum' => 'SUM(Reservation.people)'
                ],
                'conditions' => [
                    'Reservation.status' => '0'
                ],
                'group' => [
                    'Reservation.room_id'
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
]);
```

Comment: This is not Cake3, this is Cake2 syntax. Read https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#using-sql-functions

Answer (score -1):

You are getting this error because you have not defined association in your model.

[Cakephp 2.x](https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html)

Assuming Reservation has many to one relationship with Group, then you can define your association in below file like following

> app/Model Reservation.php

```
class Reservation extends AppModel {
    public $belongsTo = 'Group';

}
```

[Cakephp 3.x](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/associations.html)

> /src/Model/Table/ReservationsTable.php

```
class ReservationsTable extends Table
{
    public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        $this->belongsTo('Groups');
    }
}
```

Hope this will help!

Comment: Pls specify the reason before downvote. So that I can correct myself.